# Flask webapp generating permanent report as link

Tags: python, flask, web-applications, report, permalinks

Ok I can't find any description, which matches my problem or use-case.

I have developed a flask web-app, where a user can input some form data in the first template to make a database query. Based on the query result a second template with the output is rendered, which will rendering the results in a readable way.

My problem is, that I would like to provide a link for documentation/report where someone just opens the link and can view the same displayed report.

Or alternatively save the generated html as pdf on google drive.

Any suggestions how to do this problems?

When you see the example code, I want to open the out.html as it was rendered with the specific user input at a later point in time.

I did not find any method how to generate that link, if it is possible?

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/start')
def start():
   return render_template("start.html")

@app.route('/out')
def out():
   input = request.form
   return render_template("out.html", input=input["Test"])
```

```html
Start.html

  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <body>
  <h1>Start</h1>

  <form action = "/out" method = "POST">
          <p>Test<input type = "text" name = "Test" required/></p>
          <p><input type = "submit" value = "SUBMIT" /></p>
      </form>
  </body>
  </html>

  '''

  '''out.html

  <!doctype html>
  <html>
  <body>
  <h1>Out</h1>

  <p>{{input}}</p>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Well you could use the form method as GET and send that link after redirecting

Comment: I think I get, what you mean, but I cannot get how to do it. I am thinking about pen the website with a query string, but I can do it in flask with my build apparently.

Comment: Why is your form action `/checkspots` and not `/out` ?

Comment: Careless mistake by me. Thanks for pointing it out. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return """<form action="/result" method="GET">
          <input type="text" name="test"><input type="submit"></form>"""

@app.route("/result")
def result():
    return request.args.get("test")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

You can copy the link from the address bar which provides the same result.

**EDIT:**

I can't understand your problem. 
So I am guessing that your `{{input}}` is not getting the value.
If that so,

You need to do this in your backend:

```py
......
input = request.args.get("test")
return render_template("out.html", input=input)
......
```

**EDIT 2**

Or you can use sql database to store the input values with 16bit unique id for each new input values.

```py
....
@app.route("/<unique>")
def result(unique):
    #retrieve the input values from the database using the id
    # and render the template
```

Comment: But I loose all the user input. I won't see the input from form "test". I would need to do another input.

Comment: It was indeed the problem of computing the inputs from the query string with requeest.args. Made some dump typos, so it did not work in the beginning. Thanks for your answer. Helped me to get on the right track.